# SQL Case statement with 'or' and 'and'

Tags: sql, case-statement

Can I use a case statement as follows?

```
CASE
WHEN (condition1 = 1 or 2) 
 AND   condition2 = 3
THEN  result = 'Result'
ELSE
NULL
 END
```

Conditions 1 and 2 will be looking for different values, just fyi.

If not, is there a better way to write this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
CASE WHEN condition1 in (1, 2) AND condition2 = 3
     THEN 'Result'
     ELSE NULL
END 
AS result
```

Comment: Actually yeah that probably would. I think I was over thinking it, ha!

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on the system you are using. For example if you use Oracle and PL/SQL you can check the statement here

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php

What DB are you using? And do you want the statement in SQL or in some other kind of code or stored procedure?

Comment: I'll be using this in an Oracle PL/SQL stored procedure. It will actually be in the values section of an INSERT INTO script. Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do with the statement.  In a `select` statement, it would be:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (condition1 = 1 or 2) AND condition2 = 3
             THEN  'Result'
        END) as result
```

You don't need the `else` because `NULL` is returned by the statement automatically if none of the `when` conditions are met.

In a `where`, it would be:

```
WHERE (condition1 = 1 or 2) AND (condition2 = 3) AND (result = 'Result')
```

The `else` condition is equivalent to false.